# proxy:error AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, ssl, reverse-proxy

I have a server that acts as a front-end for a cPanel mailserver in a network. The apache proxy on the front-end server ran for 152 days without fault then suddenly I now get 500/502 errors when using it to access the webmail clients of the mailserver.

The front-end server uses a signed SSL cert, the cPanel sever is using a self signed cert. Here is the error log output from the front-end server when it first started happening:

`[Tue Sep 10 18:22:52.959291 2013] [proxy:error] [pid 19531] (502)Unknown error 502: [client 173.xx.xx.xx:9558] AH01084: pass request body failed to 184.xx.xx.xx:2096 (184.xx.xx.xx), referer: https://domain.com:2096/cpsess12385596/3rdparty/roundcube/?_task=mail&_refresh=1&_mbox=INBOX`

[Tue Sep 10 18:22:52.959469 2013] [proxy:error] [pid 19531] [client 173.xx.xx.xx:9558] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /cpsess12385596/3rdparty/roundcube/, referer: https://domain.com:2096/cpsess12385596/3rdparty/roundcube/?_task=mail&_refresh=1&_mbox=INBOX

The front-end server is an EC2 instance running `Apache/2.4.6 (Amazon)`
My VirtualHost setup for the proxy on this server is as follows:

`< VirtualHost *:2096>
    ServerName domain.com`

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off

SSLCertificateFile /x/x/x/domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /x/x/x/domain.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /x/x/x/domain.com.cabundle

ProxyPass / https://184.xx.xx.xx:2096/
ProxyPassReverse / https://184.xx.xx.xx:2096/
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 184.xx.xx.xx:2096 domain.com
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /

SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
ProxyHTMLURLMap https://184.xx.xx.xx:2096 /
```

< /VirtualHost>

As far as I can think nothing has changed on the front-end server, I didn't do an update or anything, once noticing this problem and fiddling with no success I tried a restart on both servers but it did nothing to fix this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 48):

Came across the same issue with Server version: Apache/2.4.6

As per the documentation at [1], "**In 2.4.5 and later, SSLProxyCheckPeerCN has been superseded by SSLProxyCheckPeerName, and its setting is only taken into account when SSLProxyCheckPeerName off is specified at the same time**."

So adding following entry did the trick:

**SSLProxyCheckPeerName off**

So my working config looks like...

```
    ProxyRequests Off

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

    SSLCertificateFile /x/x/keys/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /x/x/keys/server.key
```

[1] http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html

Comment: Note that "SSLEngine On" is not concerned with the proxy part of the configuration, but with _serving_ this request via SSL/TLS, even though it is grouped with the proxy config options.

Answer (score 17):

If the backend server uses out-of-date self signed certificate, one more option is needed (if there is no access to the backend server):

```
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
```

Comment: This worked for me migrating a reverse proxy from apache 2.2 to 2.4

Answer (score 3):

I'm also getting the same error but in my case, the accepted answer here solved this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718508/apache-proxypass-https-and-remote-server-with-sni

I added

```
ProxyAddHeaders off
ProxyPreserveHost off
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why it *suddenly* fails, but I just ran into a similar case where apache failed to connect as proxy to another HTTPS-server, which was running on a non-standard port.

The solution in my case: If you want to connect to:

```
ProxyPass / https://184.xx.xx.xx:2096/
```

then also add:

```
AllowCONNECT 443 2096
```

(i.e. add the port `2096` to the list of ports apache is allowed to make `CONNECT` requests to, to start a TLS-connection)

See also: Apache HTTPD reference documentation [AllowCONNECT in the mod_proxy_connect module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_connect.html#allowconnect)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to restart the back-end server after renewing its certificates, in case it doesn't detect, whether the certificate files had been updated. So you won't need to set the `SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off` directive.